# React context (this.context) is undefined at constructor call time

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-context

I am trying to write a class component that uses values from `this.context` to derive a state object. I have a method `getStyle` that returns such an object. At `constructor` time, I am calling `this.getStyle` to start off with an already up-to-date state, and speed up the initial rendering.

However, it seems that, at `constructor` call time, `this.context` is `undefined`, and it remains such until `render` call time.

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

I don't recall any details related to such issue in React's (new) context API docs. `this.context` is available at `componentDidMount` time, however, this would require a `setState`, which will cause an extra component re-render which I would like to avoid.

Below is the code that I'm trying to use:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";


const defaultTheme = {
    light: { backgroundColor: "white" },
    dark: { backgroundColor: "black" }
};

const customTheme = {
    light: { backgroundColor: "#EEE" },
    dark: { backgroundColor: "#111" },
};

const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultTheme);


class Container extends React.PureComponent {
    static contextType = MyContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = this.getStyle();   // TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.context[_this.props.colorScheme || "light"]')
        // this.state = {}; // use this to try the componentDidMount alternative
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const style = this.getStyle();
        this.setState(style);
    }

    getStyle = () => {
        // this.props.colorScheme = "light" | "dark" | null | undefined
        return this.context[this.props.colorScheme || "light"];
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState, snapshot) => {
        if (prevProps.colorScheme !== this.props.colorScheme) {
            const style = this.getStyle();
            this.setState(style);
        }
    }

    render = () => {
        return <View style={this.state}>
            {this.props.children}
        </View>;
    }
}


export default function App() {
    return <MyContext.Provider value={customTheme}>
        <Container>
            <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
        </Container>
    </MyContext.Provider>
}
```

Comment: I think this is a premature optimization. A single extra render after the component mounts is probably not going to have much of an impact on performance. I think the difficulty here is more in how you're going to update colorScheme and/or the theme (From a different component than App) using context.

Comment: Yes, a single re-render may not impact a single component, but I am making some general purpose components, that will potentially be nested at many levels deep. I have already tried this, and it gives a small dip at the initial render, similar to a flicker. If I could start off ready-to-go, it would completely eliminate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing context to constructor:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    // your code here
}
```

This solution might be deprecated according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6598) but you can try.

Comment: That syntax is deprecated since the new Context API in React 16. I think that React 17 totally removed support for it. However, i found another usable solution, i will post an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this using React 18+, the only way I could get this to work was to access `this.conext` inside of the `render()` method in a class component.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution other than the ones posted above: context wrapper component, passing context as props.
You create a Wrapper component that in its render function uses the context value, and passes it on to the component where you need those props at constructor time:

```
class TheActualComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.context); // Now you've got'em
    }

    // ...
}

// SFC wrapper
function WrapperComponent(props) {
    const contextProps = React.useContext(MyContext);

    return <TheActualComponent {...props} context={contextProps}>
        {props.children}
    </TheActualComponent>;
}

// class component wrapper
class WrapperClassComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    static contextType = MyContext;
    render() {
        return <TheActualComponent {...this.props} context={this.context}>
            {this.props.children}
        </TheActualComponent>;
    }
}
```